# Android - getting different values for PIXEL in java and NDK

Tags: android, c++, image-processing, android-ndk, pixel

After reading some tutorials on image processing in android, some which are related to java others with native languages like c++. I tried some code on my own. the problem is that I got different results. when printing the pixels values on both sides (Java and NDK). 
C++:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_example_test(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject bmp){
        AndroidBitmapInfo infocolor;
        void* pixelscolor;
        int ret;
        uint32_t *pixel;
        if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bmp, &infocolor)) < 0) {
            //return null;
        }

        if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bmp, &pixelscolor)) < 0) {
        }

        int pixelsPerRow = infocolor.stride / 4;

        pixel = (uint32_t *) pixelscolor;                

                for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {

                        LOGI("******************************************** native %d", (*(pixel + i + (j ) *pixelsPerRow))) ;
                    }}.....
```

Java:

```
public static double[][] test(Bitmap img) {


        int width = img.getWidth();
        int height = img.getHeight();

        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {

            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                System.out.printf("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java %d\n",img.getPixel(i, j));
            }}.....
```

Some output are:

```
07-02 14:41:24.284: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14540078
07-02 14:41:24.284: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14408492
07-02 14:41:24.284: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14671664
07-02 14:41:24.284: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14671403
07-02 14:41:24.284: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14934575
07-02 14:41:24.284: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -15000113
07-02 14:41:24.284: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -15000113
07-02 14:41:24.284: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14803503
07-02 14:41:24.284: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14935089
07-02 14:41:24.284: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14474285
07-02 14:41:24.284: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14540078
07-02 14:41:24.284: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14605871
07-02 14:41:24.284: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14737196
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14934575
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -15000113
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -15000113
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14803503
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14869296
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14605616
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14605869
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14671662
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14671917
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14803503
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -15065138
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -15196724
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14672944
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14738737
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14605616
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14605869
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14605869
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14606124
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14737710
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -15130931
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -15130931
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14672944
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14672944
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14606130
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14408751
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14540337
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14409263
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14606642
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14606130
07-02 14:41:24.294: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14737716
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14672432
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14935604
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14408751
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14342958
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14540337
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14409263
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14475056
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14606130
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14671923
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14672432
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14869811
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14408752
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14408751
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14540337
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14606130
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14540337
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14606130
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14606130
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14737716
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14935095
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14408752
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14540337
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14671923
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14606130
07-02 14:41:24.314: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14606130
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14606130
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14671923
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14737716
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14935095
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14606130
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14671924
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14737717
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14475056
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14540849
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14868019
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14868019
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14476855
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14542648
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14606130
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14737717
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14737717
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14540849
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14606642
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14933812
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -15065398
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14542648
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -14411062
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/lib(10111): ******************************************** native -207447

07-02 14:41:24.324: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3005918
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -2874332
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3137504
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -2809568
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3072740
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3203813
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3203813
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3072738
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3204324
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -2940125
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3005918
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3071711
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -2875361
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3072740
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3203813
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3203813
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3072738
07-02 14:41:24.324: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3138531
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3136991
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -2940639
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3006432
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -2941152
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3072738
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3268838
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3400424
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3138784
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3204577
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3136991
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -2940639
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -2940639
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -2875359
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3006945
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3334631
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3334631
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3138784
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3138784
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3268575
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3071196
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3202782
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3071708
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3269087
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3268575
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3400161
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3138272
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3401444
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3071196
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3005403
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3202782
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3071708
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3137501
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3268575
07-02 14:41:24.334: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3334368
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3138272
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3335651
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3136732
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3071196
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3202782
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3268575
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3202782
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3268575
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3268575
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3400161
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3597540
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3136732
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3202782
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3334368
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3268575
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3268575
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3268575
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3334368
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3400161
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3597540
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3268575
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3399904
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3465697
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3137501
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3203294
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3333859
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3333859
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3598045
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3663838
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3268575
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3465697
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3465697
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3203294
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3269087
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3399652
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3531238
07-02 14:41:24.344: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3663838
07-02 14:41:24.354: I/System.out(10111): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ java -3532252
```

Any clue that can help?!!, It's really bizarre.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing special, Bitmap.getPixel simply changes the color component order.

The pixels you're trying to print are like `FF2424D4` in one case and `FFD42424` in the other.

From the Bitmap.getPixel documentation:

> The components are stored as follows `(alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue`

On the C++ side, you're seeing `(alpha << 24) | (blue << 16) | (green << 8) | red`